# Solving the trigonometric equation $\sin(x) + \sin(2x) + \sin(3x) - \sqrt 3 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, computer-algebra-systems

Anybody can solve this equation for me?
$$\sin(x) + \sin(2x) + \sin(3x) - \sqrt 3 = 0.$$
I imported it to my cas calculator and this was the output:
$$\left\{x = 2k π + (1/3) π, x = 2k π + 0.3202568022849\right\}$$
The problem is I don't know were the $0.3202568022849$ is coming from and it should not be as constant number I have to write it as mathematical form.

Comment: You take the only real root of $x^5 + x^4 + 58 x^3 - 78 x^2 + 117 x - 3$ which is $0.02608587050\ldots$ and I denote it by $x_0$. Then your constant is $2\arctan(\sqrt{x_0})=0.3202568022\ldots\,$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+sin%28x%29%2Bsin%282x%29%2Bsin%283x%29%3Dsqrt%283%29).

Comment: As you might know, $5$th or higher degree polynomials cannot be solved via radicals in general. So there is a good chance that the root $x_0$ cannot be expressed in an explicit form.

Comment: how did you come across this eqn and why do you need to write it in "mathematical form"?

Comment: Rewriting i.t.o. $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ to get $2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+4\sin(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)=\sqrt{3}$ and using M2 gröbner bases i.e. eliminating to get everything i.t.o. $\sin(\theta)$ using only $\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)=1:$

`R=QQ[c,s,u,MonomialOrder=>Lex]`
`I=ideal(2*c*s+4*s*c^2-u,c^2+s^2-1,u^2-3)`
`gens gb I -- matrix {{u^2-3, 16*s^6-28*s^4+8*s^3*u+12*s^2-8*s*u+3, 3*c+8*s^5*u-14*s^3*u+6*s^2+6*s*u-6}}`

Comment: $16\sin^6(\theta)-28\sin^4(\theta)+8\sqrt{3}\sin^3(\theta)+12\sin^2(\theta)-8\sqrt{3}\sin(\theta)+3=0$ or 

$16 \; \left(\sin(\theta) - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right) \; \left(\sin^{5}(\theta) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \; \sin^{4}(\theta) - \sin^{3}(\theta) + \frac{3}{4} \; \sin(\theta) - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8} \right)=0.$

$\sin(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ or $\sin(\theta)=0.31481,$ the other four roots being non-real.

So $\theta=0.320$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3},$

Comment: but also the extraneous $\theta=2.821$ and $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ in $[0,2\pi)$, that we can rule out by using the other relation

$3\cos(\theta)+8\sqrt3\sin^5(\theta)-14\sqrt3\sin^3(\theta)+6\sin^2(\theta)+6\sqrt3\sin(\theta)-6=0.$

Comment: @Gary thank. How did you get x^5 + x^4 +58x^3..... And What is the relation between this equation and my equation?

Comment: @AlirezaKarkon First you  make a substitution $t=\tan(x/2)$. This will transfrom your equation to $$
\frac{{4t(t^4  - 4t^2  + 3)}}{{(t^2  + 1)^3 }} = \sqrt 3 .
$$ Now square both sides and call $z=t^2$ and re-arrange to get $$
(1 - 3z)(z^5  + z^4  + 58z^3  - 78z^2  + 117z - 3) = 0.
$$ The solution $z=1/3$ will correspond to $x=\pi/3+2\pi k$ and the only real solution of the 5th order part gives you the other set of roots with that number $0.32\ldots\,$.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could do it...

1. Use the sum-to-product formulas (preferably one that makes the angles simple), factor, and then determine which root is correct.
2. Expand $\sin 2x$ and $\sin 3x$, group like terms, and then determine which root is correct.